# Prefetching error using react-router in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I got this  error while trying to prefetch the data

```
react_query__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.QueryClient.prefetchQuery is not a function
```

This is my code

```
 const formReducer = (state, event) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  };
};

export default function InsertForm() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useReducer(formReducer, {});
  const addMutation = useMutation(addOneUser,{
    //fonction efa vita de mandeha ho azy le onsuccess 
    onSuccess: async () =>{
//This should work, here the model is the user and the method for fetching the response is  getUser
       await QueryClient.prefetchQuery(['user'], getUser);
    }
  })
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(Object.keys(formData).length == 0) return console.log("Tsy misy donnes ao @ le formulaire");
    

     let{nom,
          mail,
          dept,
          status }= formData;

    const model={
      nom,
      avatar:`https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/${Math.floor(Math.random()*10)}.jpg`,
      mail,
      dept,
      status:status ?? "Active"
    }

    console.log(model,"mandeha tsara ny modelisation");
    addMutation.mutate(model); 

  };
```

I try to mutate the data through a model,  I don't know what I've done wrong. I'm new to NextJs

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that could be causing this issue. First, make sure that you are using the latest version of react-query. Second, make sure that you are passing the correct parameters to the prefetchQuery method. The first parameter should be an array of queries, and the second parameter should be a function that returns a promise.

```
const formReducer = (state, event) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  };
};

export default function InsertForm() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useReducer(formReducer, {});
  const addMutation = useMutation(addOneUser,{
    //fonction efa vita de mandeha ho azy le onsuccess 
    onSuccess: async () =>{
//This should work, here the model is the user and the method for fetching the response is  getUser
       await QueryClient.prefetchQuery(['user'], getUser);
    }
  })
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(Object.keys(formData).length == 0) return console.log("Tsy misy donnes ao @ le formulaire");
    

     let{nom,
          mail,
          dept,
          status }= formData;

    const model={
      nom,
      avatar:`https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/${Math.floor(Math.random()*10)}.jpg`,
      mail,
      dept,
      status:status ?? "Active"
    }

    console.log(model,"mandeha tsara ny modelisation");
    addMutation.mutate(model); 

  };
```

}